# Selecting lots of data async from database with EF6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await

What I am trying to do is to fetch rows from a table with approximatly 4 million rows to index it against ElasticSearch.

The underlying indexer will use IndexManyAsync and batch up the enumerable given to it.

Something like:

```
public void IndexMany(IEnumerable<IIndexModel> indexModels) {
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
    var batches = indexModels.Batch(1000);
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    Parallels.ForEach(partitions, partition =>
    {
        var task = client.IndexManyAsync(partition);
        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

so with that in mind I would like to create an enumerable with IndexModels.

IndexModels will take an entity and initialize various properties through the given entity. Something like:

```
public class FooModel<T> : IIndexModel
{
    public FooModel(T entity) 
    {
        Name = entity.Name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have a table which contains ~4mil rows which will obviously take some time to query. So what I would like to do is to do this async.

I have tried various ways of doing this. First approach was to batch up the query and do a parallels foreach on it. This gave various concurrency problems with ObjectContext.

```
public void IndexAllModels() {
    using (var db = new Db()) {
        var batchedEntities = db.BigTable.Select(p => p).Batch(1000);

        Parallels.ForEach(batchedEntities, currentBatch =>
        {
            var indexModels = new List<IIndexModel>();
            foreach (var entity in currentBatch) 
            {
                var indexModel = new FooModel<BigTable>(entity);
                indexModels.Add(indexModel);
            }

            IndexMany(indexModels);
        }
    }
}
```

What I wonder is if there is any way of doing this by using the new EF6 async operations?

Comment: What's the size of `indexModels`?

Comment: May vary. Some indexmodels sets around ~20 properties and some just 5 or so.

Comment: As many as around 4 million index models.

Comment: Why are you using an ORM to crawl a database when ElasticSearch supports that already through JDBC connections? You get no benefit from using the ORM (there *are no* objects involved) but you do add significant overhead by going through an intermediary that just passes the data along

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of using naturally `async` APIs is that you don't need to use threads to use them. Since all the way down to the WinAPI level, [There Is No Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

You can create a method which takes an `IEnumerable<IndexModel>` and use's ElasticSearchs async API like so:

```
public async Task IndexManyAsync(IEnumerable<IIndexModel> indexModels) 
{
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    var taskBatches = indexModels.Batch(1000)
                                 .Select(partition =>
                                         client.IndexManyAsync(partition));

    await Task.WhenAll(taskBatches);
}
```

Assuming `IndexManyAsync` uses a separate `DbContext` for each request, this should work.

Comment: Thanks! This explains some. However, this doesn't answer the question on how to retrieve large chunks of data from the database async.
I may not have been very clear in my question.
But selecting 4 mill rows may also be a memory problem.

Comment: @Ekenstein Oh, i thought you were already using `Batch` to process each 1000 requests.

Comment: Yes. I use morelinq to batch up the query. However, when trying to fetch each batch using parallel foreach it becomes troublesome since objectcontext doesn't seem to be threadsafe.

Also, I would also prefer to instantiate an index model for each entity parallel aswell.

Comment: @Ekenstein Why do you use an ORM to crawl the database? You'll never achieve the same speed as ElasticSearch crawling it directly, not to mention that ORMs are unsuitable for batch/set operations.

Comment: Some information from the database should not be indexed. That's why.

Comment: @Ekenstein you can do that by specifying a view instead of the table itself. Even if you *had* to use an intermediate processing step (eg for some complex calculation that can't be epxressed in SQL) it would be far faster, easier and cheaper to use a SqlReader as a firehose cursor and send each processed row to ElasticSearch immediately or in batches. Concurrency would *only* help if you wanted multiple such *channels* to load data from the database concurrently - assuming ElasticSearch can handle that load

Comment: Ah nice! Didn't think of that :) That is actually a great solution for this. Thanks!